# Syntax highlighting with CodeRay and Markdown (RDiscount) in a Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coderay, rdiscount

I'm trying to add some syntax highlighting to my blog that currently uses RDiscount. I am converting the Markdown to HTML with RDiscount then parsing the HTML code blocks with CodeRay to add syntax highlighting. This is what I have so far:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :render_body

  def render_body
    self.rendered_body = coderay(markdown(self.body))
  end

  def markdown(text)
    RDiscount.new(text).to_html
  end

  def coderay(text)
    text.gsub(/\<code( lang="(.+?)")?\>(.+?)\<\/code\>/m) do
      CodeRay.scan($3, $2).div(:css => :class)
    end
  end
end
```

And in my view:

```
<%= raw @post.rendered_body %>
```

Using this markdown:

```
<code lang="ruby">
def function(param1, param2)
  puts param1
    param2.each do |a|
      a.hello :world
    end
end
</code>
```

The result is that the code blocks are being wrapped twice.

```
<pre>
<div class="CodeRay">
<div class="code">
<pre>
def function(param1, param2)
  puts param1
  param2.each do |a|
    a.hello :world
  end
end
</pre>
</div>
</div>
</pre>
```

What should I do instead?

Comment: Can you include the full self.body in this case?

Comment: Were you able to test my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `render_body` method call the `coderay()` method before calling the `markdown()` method. Using the `markdown` method first was generating some extra html and this confused `CodeRay` causing bad output.

My tests assumed you had the raw data that looked something like this in the markdown source

```
<code lang="ruby">
      def function(param1, param2)
        puts param1
          param2.each do |a|
            a.hello :world
          end
      end
</code>
```

Here's the complete class I used to test it. Note I didn't use `:css => :class` option because I didn't have the css to test it.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :render_body

  def render_body
    self.rendered_body = markdown(coderay(self.body))
  end

  def markdown(text)
    RDiscount.new(text).to_html
  end

  def coderay(text)
    text.gsub(/\<code( lang="(.+?)")?\>(.+?)\<\/code\>/m) do
      CodeRay.scan($3, $2).div
   end
  end
end
```

Your final output assuming the `:css => :class` option should now look something like this

```
<div class="CodeRay"> 
  <div class="code"><pre> 
      <span class="r">def</span> <span class="fu">function</span>(param1, param2)
        puts param1
          param2.each <span class="r">do</span> |a|
            a.hello <span class="sy">:world</span> 
          <span class="r">end</span> 
      <span class="r">end</span> 
</pre></div> 
</div>
```