# Prevent double escaping with CodeRay and RDiscount

Tags: ruby, markdown

I am looking for the most straight forward way to have code syntax highlighting in markdown, using Ruby (without Rails).

I have tried some things with Kramdown and Rouge, and could not make it work, so I am now working with **RDiscount** and **CodeRay**.

Most of the things work as I expect, with one small and one big issue:

1. Small Issue: The only way I found to make CodeRay work with RDiscount, is by applying the highlighting **on the HTML** rather than **on the markdown** document. This seems a little off to me and prone to errors. Is there another way?
2. Big Issue: I am now facing a **double HTML escaping** issue, and was unable to find any `html_escape: false` option in the [CodeRay documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/coderay/CodeRay/Encoders/HTML).

#### Code

````
require 'rdiscount'
require 'coderay'

markdown = <<EOF
```ruby
A > B
```
EOF

def coderay(text)
  text.gsub(/\<code class="(.+?)"\>(.+?)\<\/code\>/m) do
    CodeRay.scan($2, $1).html
  end
end

html = RDiscount.new(markdown).to_html
html = coderay(html)

puts html
````

#### Output

Notice the double escaping on the greater than sign:

```
<pre>
  <span class="constant">A</span> &amp;gt; <span class="constant">B</span>
</pre>
```

I have found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994063/syntax-highlighting-with-coderay-and-markdown-rdiscount-in-a-rails-3-applicati), but its old and without a solution for this case.

The only way I can come up with, is to unescape the HTML before passing it through CodeRay, but this does not feel right to me. Nevertheless, a working alternative below:

```
def coderay(text)
  text.gsub(/\<code class="(.+?)"\>(.+?)\<\/code\>/m) do
    lang, code = $1, $2
    code = CGI.unescapeHTML code
    CodeRay.scan(code, lang).html
  end
end
```

Comment: Is the problem caused by rdiscount or coderay? Is the value between the two OK? Try narrowing the scope of your question, or separate the question in two.

Comment: It is CodeRay that does the extra encoding. RDiscount encodes, but it should. CodeRay should have the ability to disable escaping I think. The reason I posted it in a single question, is that I am hopeful there is a better way to get markdown with syntax highlighting.